# How to enable CORS for web sockets using ws library in node js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, websocket, ssl-certificate, ws

I am trying to create a web socket using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) in node js.
I have two questions:

1. I do have an idea that CORS is not available for web sockets but is there a way I can still enable them?
2. How I can extend the code to implement Client authentication ? Currently, I can use "wss" but I want to authenticate the client using the certificate.. How can I do that ?

Server.js Code

```
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

function startServer() {

 const server = createServer({
   cert: readFileSync('server_cert.pem'),
   key: readFileSync('server_key.pem'),
 });
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  authenticate(request, (err, client) => {
  if (err || !client) {
    socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
    socket.destroy();
    return;
  }

  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
    wss.emit('connection', ws, request, client);
   });
  });
});
server.listen(7070);
}
```

Comment: There are no CORS restrictions for websockets, so there is nothing to enable.

Comment: @Tomalak There is no way to validate the origin ?

Comment: No. The websocket protocol does not impose any restrictions on cross-origin connections at all. There is nothing there that you could possibly enable.

Comment: @Tomalak Can I validate it in the httpServer ?

Comment: No. The server generally talks to anybody, as long as there are no firewalls or settings (e.g. IP blacklists, or client certificate requirements) preventing it. This is also true of CORS: The server talks to anybody. CORS is a self-imposed, voluntary, client-side restriction. It's not a physical part of the HTTP protocol, it's just your browser refusing to do certain things that it could technically do. You could fork Firefox and build a version that does not impose CORS- or same-origin restrictions on HTTP connections.

Comment: So it comes down to what you mean by "validate". As the server you always have the option to force clients to identify themselves properly (i.e. "authentication"), and to refuse those clients who can't (i.e. "authorization"). But with web sockets, you would have to implement your own authentication/authorization scheme.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak for the detailed answer... Seems like I need to switch to Socket.io library since it provides a feature to enable the CORS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242693/discussion-between-jaspreet-chhabra-and-tomalak).

Comment: Okay, again. There is no CORS in websockets. There is no library that can enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved CORS validation and Certificate based Client Authentication using the following Server side code:

```
const server = createServer({
  cert: readFileSync(config.certs.sslCertPath),
  key: readFileSync(config.certs.sslKeyPath),
  ca: [readFileSync(config.certs.caCertPath)],
  requestCert: true,
});
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  const origin = request && request.headers && request.headers.origin;
  const corsRegex = /^https?:\/\/(.*\.?)abc\.com(:\d+)?\/$/g
  if (origin && origin.match(corsRegex) != null) {
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
  } else {
    socket.destroy();
  }
});
```